# Getting info about number of views about all videos from query using YouTube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, http-get

I have to get videos information for a specified **search_text** and, particularly, the number of views of each video. I've already managed to get JSON containing *video_id*, *title*, *thumbnails* and *channel_name* using this query `'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' + query + '&key={My_key}'`.
Obviously, I can make queries for each video_id to get it's number of views, but it's not what I'm looking for.
Is it possible to get number of views alongside with all data using only 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API v3 doesn't provide this possibility. It was possible in the previous API version, but not in the v3.

This functionality has been asked many times and youtube should really implement it. 
The workaround requires 2 queries. You don't have to create request for each video_id.

First, you need to use the search query, provided in your post

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' + query + '&key={My_key}
```

After that you can take all the videoId values and request statistics from them at the same time. Seperate the id's with comma, and you'll get statistics about all the videos.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=vnuTOBQ1Nyo,2a4Uxdy9TQY&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response will be

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/cxUC3oHfAMGCbF9gjuO11C2VsEA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 2,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/C37CAxmH_BPj81a6LHiDRO7Ruqc\"",
   "id": "vnuTOBQ1Nyo",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "13117",
    "likeCount": "1251",
    "dislikeCount": "26",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "102"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/EWOT7bD_VfD0Wu52Tk_rInSgoE0\"",
   "id": "2a4Uxdy9TQY",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "5576961",
    "likeCount": "77132",
    "dislikeCount": "8652",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "22797"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```